# Maintenance funds for sponsor for UK visit visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My parents are planning to apply for a UK visit visa next month. Although my parents are both employed , I have mentioned on their cover letter that I will be bearing all the expenses during their trip. I have also mentioned that they are coming only for 10 days. 
However I was a bit worried about the funds that I need to show in mu current account. Although they show my salary going into the account. The balance at the moment is only about 500 pounds as we brought a house recently.

I am worried their application will be refused due to this reason. Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth giving this a read: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e/92122#92122

There's a good section on sponsorship.

Comment: There's also a part on "Funds Parking, Lifestyle, and Credibility" which should help with your comment in the answer below (and includes a link to another answer explaining what constitutes a healthy looking account for proving funds).

Answer (score 1):

If your parents *can* pay their own expenses, it will make a stronger visa application to say they will. Sponsored applications are not a special gold-plated class of applicants; it's a way to pull otherwise hopeless applications into "barely scrapes by" territory.

Of course, if your parents are going to stay at your house, say so and document that you have the right to invite them in (that is, by owning the house).

But unless you *need* to claim you will pay for their food, entertainment, etc. during the visit in order to paint a convincing picture, don't bother with that.

This doesn't mean that you cannot all *actually* eat meals that come out of your own groceries budget -- just that you shouldn't (and are not expected to) complicate the visa applications with it if they can show for themselves that they *would* be able to eat out instead.

If you're paying their *travel* costs, that's a different matter. But that's also simpler because that's a more or less definite amount that you either have available or you don't.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. s there a specific amount they they require to show in their accounts other than the property and assets they own?